# Help with SAGE/python: removing elements from a list with respect to an equivalence relation

Tags: python, sagemath

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right forum for this but here goes: Let $l$ be a prime and let $p\equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ l)$ be prime as well. Let $\zeta \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a primitive $l$-th root of unity modulo $p$. I have a list of integers, call it $B$. I will call two numbers $a,b$ from $B$ equivalent if $a \equiv \zeta^kb \ (\text{mod} \ p)$ for some $k=0,...,l-1$. I would like to create a new list $A$ containing one and only one element from the equivalence classes of $B$. For example if $l=5,p=31, \zeta=2$ and $B=\{3,4,17\}$, then $A=\{3,4\}$ since $3 \not \equiv 2^k4 \ (\text{mod} \ 31)$ for all $k$ and $3 \equiv 2^117 \ (\text{mod} \ 31)$. I have a very limited understanding of coding. I know that I probably need to create a list $A$ containing the first element of $B$ and then do a for loop running through the elements $B[i]$ of $B$, then within that loop, run through the elements $a$ of $A$ and if $B[i]\not \equiv \zeta^ka \ (\text{mod} \ p)$ for all $k$, then $A.append(B[i])$. What I'm struggling with is how to add the element $B[i]$ once it has "passed this test" and how do I get the loop to move past $B[i]$ once it has failed the test. I'm not sure if I should be using for loops or while loops. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The standard algorithm for partitioning a set into equivalence classes is called *union-find*.  You might try Googling that.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you want to do some kind of loop. If I understand you correctly, you want to do this:

```
# assuming you have p, l, zeta, and B already defined
A = []
for b in B:
    keep_b = True
    for a in A:
        b_equiv_a = False
        for k in range(l):
            if a == zeta^k * b:
                b_equiv_a = True

        if b_equiv_a:
            keep_b = False

    if keep_b:
        A.append(b)
```

It's worth reading this carefully and trying to understand what it does. For each $b$, we check it against each $a$. If ever $b \sim a$, we set `keep_b = False` so that when we know to through $b$ out. If `keep_b` manages to be `True` at the end, that means it survived testing against each $a \in A$, so it's from a new equivalence class. We keep it, and now that it's in $A$ we'll check future $b$s against *it* as well.

There are slicker approaches (There's a couple obvious optimizations and I'm sure there's many that I don't see), but my goal with this code was ease-of-understanding. If you want to optimize it, you might ask on the [sage forum](https://ask.sagemath.org) or on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! I think what I didn't see before was the "trick" to set b_equiv_a=True when there's a match and do nothing when there isn't a match so that it isn't "reset" on the next k (which won't be a match if the one before it was). This was a big help.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answered your question you should mark it as such (by clicking the checkmark next to it) so that other users know how to spend their time ^_^

Comment: It answered my question. Done!